# How do you print the start date of an msg?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have an msg that appears to be a reply to a calendar item. The msg has the properties "StartDate", "EndDate", and "Location" when I view the email in Outlook. But when I try to print it those fields are blank.

Is there any way to print the email with those fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rare event someone else runs into this problem the solution is to change the mime-type of the item to a calendar item.